# Office for Mac 2011 does not start, how do I repair the database?

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2011

After a TimeMachine restore; Office 2011 is having kittens over permissions it would seem. Having attempted a 'repair' out of Disk Utility, am still seeing:

> there is a problem with the Office database

upon startup, after which Word/Excel work without issues.

Outlook on the other hand won't even start. Given the obvious message here "You do not have write access to the Outlook application folder" – where is the DB located to check?

Comment: "kittens?"  where do they come out of?  Are they cute?

Comment: with regards to the outlook problem does when you click outlook does it open close straight away?

Answer (score 1):

The data base should be in `~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/`
Inside should be the database file simply named "Database". If you fix the permissions(Get Info-> Sharing and Permissions) and it still isn't working, there is a repair tool called Microsoft Database Utility located in `/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office/` that should be able to fix any remaining issue with the database.

Comment: Problem is - even after I remove everything office related (including the folder you mention), and re-install office, it still appears. So there's something else out there :(

Comment: Do you also have access to write to /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011 /Library/Application Support/Microsoft and ~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft ?